# WPF - Should custom control attribute order matter?

Tags: wpf

If I write a custom WPF control, should I insure that the order in which the attributes are set in XAML do not affect the behavior of the control. For example:

```
<MyControl Prop1="Value" Prop2="Value" Prop3="Value" />
```

If the above XAML is instead written

```
<MyControl Prop3="Value" Prop2="Value" Prop1="Value" />
```

Should the user expect the state of the control to be the same in both cases?
Or is it ok that I require the order to matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not enforce the developer to follow such the attribute order. You cannot require that a developer remembers the right order to write the attributes.

I, eg., use an plugin that automatically orders the attributes.

Comment: What the plagin you use?

Comment: I use the ReSharper plugin `Xaml Attritbute Ordering Plugin.`

Answer (score 2):

Order does not matter.  The object is created & its properties set before any UI events occur.  In fact, the XML specification says that attribute order is not defined & makes no difference.

Comment: The question is whether its ok to write a custom control in which order *does* matter

Comment: You can't do that, can you?  How could you make the XAML parser do that?

Comment: Can you show me where the specification states that attribute order is not defined and makes no difference? There is a difference in "the order doesn't matter" and "make sure the order doesn't affect the controls behavior."

Comment: The XAML parser is going to call the setters on your custom properties one at a time and those setters could do crazy things... or benevolent things that yield crazy behavior.  For example,  validating one property based on the value of another.  You would want to hold off on doing that validation until the control is first rendered.

Comment: If you create your dependency property and it contains some logic (for example in PropertyMetadata) which requires property B for property A, it thus creates a dependency between these properties, in this case the order is important.

Comment: And yet, [XAML attribute order matters](http://www.nickdarnell.com/xaml-attribute-order-matters/), at least in some cases, especially when using bindings

Comment: According to the design guidelines you should design a control such that the order does not matter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property.

Answer (score 0):

For standart XAML properties, the order can be arbitrary. But, if you create your own `UserControl`, the order can be important if the logic of your properties in `PropertyMetadata` has a dependency on some parameters-properties.

I think, the good practice to create a Control without specifying parameters in some order, because it's hard to remember all the order of properties, therefore it is not convenient for the end user.

For dependency properties, I use a *default value* if the user does not specify this value. Control should be designed so that some values ​​can not be specified at all or not in the correct order.